# Software installation exits

Tags: software-installation, texlive

When installing TeXlive full from command line, at 70% the terminal returns:

```
E: Failed to fetch 
http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tcltk-defaults`/tk_8.6.0+9_amd64.deb

Cannot initiate the connection to ar.archive.ubuntu.com:80 . - connect (101: 
Network is unreachable)

    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

**Question**

Is this a Network problem or something else? Is it possible to restart installation from the exit point (70%)?

Comment: Change the server and try again.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia How? And does it start from 0 progress?

Comment: Change it at "Software & Updates". *If* there was a problem with your local server that is not network wide the new server should work where the current one failed. It will resume downloading the file that failed, what was downloaded before is already there.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I've changed the server. Now 'apt-get install texlive' automatically returns without overwritting? Thanks for your help and patience

Comment: I've posted as an answer. You can accept and upvote if you found it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a Network problem or something else?

Yes, and hopefully temporary. You can change the server and retry the installation.

> Is it possible to restart installation from the exit point (70%)?

The installation will resume from the point were it failed. It will download the file mentioned in the error message, it won't download again the files that were successfully downloaded in the first attempt.

Comment: Perfect. What I dont understand is: how do I restart the installation? With apt-get install texlive?

Comment: Yes, just repeat the same command as before.